# Selection sort of a singular linked list

Tags: c++

I need to develop an algorithm to do a selection sort of a singular linked list, that doesn't allocate or free any memory, Does the code below do that? How would I modify this code to use for loops instead of the while loops?

```
/**************************  SortList ************************************

Description  Arranges the singly linked list pointed to by List in
natural order.  It is assumed that the list has a dummy
head node.

The algorithm used is a linked variation of the selection
sort and works like this:
Start with EndSorted aimed at first node of list

repeat
Find smallest char between EndSorted and end of list
Swap smallest element with char in EndSorted
Change EndSorted to next node
until we get to end of list

None of the pointers in linked list are changed

Parameters
IN, List  A pointer to a singly linked list with a dummy head node
-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
typedef Node* NodePtr;
void SortList(NodePtr List)
{
    NodePtr SmallNode;        //points to smallest char
    NodePtr SearchNode;       //used to search each node in list
    NodePtr EndSorted;       //points to list to sort
    char TempCh;
if (List->Link != NULL) //List is not empty
    EndSorted = List->Link; //make EndSorted point to the beginning of List

else  //List is empty
    EndSorted = List; //EndSorted points to dummy head Node and the following loop 

                      //will never execute

while (EndSorted->Link != NULL) //make sure EndSorted is not at the end of List

{
    SmallNode = EndSorted;  //give SmallNode a starting value

    SearchNode = EndSorted->Link; //make SearchNode point to the Node after EndSorted

    while (SearchNode != NULL) //make sure SearchNode is not at the end of List
    {
        if (SearchNode->Ch < SmallNode->Ch) //check the Ch value of the two Nodes

            SmallNode = SearchNode; //if SearchNode -> Ch is smaller then SmallNode -> Ch

                                    //make SmallNode point to SearchNode

        SearchNode = SearchNode->Link; //advance SearchNode to the next Node
    }

    TempCh = EndSorted->Ch; //place the Ch value in EndSorted in TempCh

    EndSorted->Ch = SmallNode->Ch; //swap SmallNode -> Ch with EndSorted -> Ch

                                   //This places the smallest unsorted value in List at the beginning
    SmallNode->Ch = TempCh;

    EndSorted = EndSorted->Link; //advance EndSorted to the next Node
}
}
```

So it should look like this?

```
void SortList(NodePtr List)
{
    NodePtr SmallNode;        //points to smallest char
    NodePtr SearchNode;       //used to search each node in list
    NodePtr EndSorted;       //points to list to sort
    char TempCh;

    if (List->Link != NULL) //Makes sure the list is not empty
    {
        /* (Points EndSorted at the first non-dummy node node; While EndSorted is not at the end of the list;
        Advance EndSorted to the next node) */

        for (EndSorted = List->Link; EndSorted->Link != NULL; EndSorted = EndSorted->Link)

        {

            SmallNode = EndSorted; //Start SmallNode with the data of the first (Non-Dummy) Node


            /*Points SearchNode at the Node after the Current EndSorted location; While Search Node is not at the end of the list; 
            Advance SearchNode to The next node*/

            for (SearchNode = EndSorted->Link; SearchNode != NULL; SearchNode = SearchNode->Link)
            {
                if (SearchNode->Ch < SmallNode->Ch) //compares the values of the two nodes
                {

                    SmallNode = SearchNode; //if search node is smaller, swap them
                }                           //to update the smallest node on this pass
                                            //once all values have been checked, and the smallest is found
                                            //it will be moved to the front of the list, or, after the node
                                            //it is slightly larger than



            }   //smallest node has been found, begin swap and end the inner while loop

            TempCh = EndSorted->Ch; //TempCh holds the value of the Ch held by EndSorted

            EndSorted->Ch = SmallNode->Ch; //EndSorted now holds the smallest unsorted node's value

            SmallNode->Ch = TempCh; //SmallNode now holds the value EndSorted originally held


        }                               
    }
}
```

Comment: Posting code and then asking us what it does is not a great approach here.  Any `while(x)` can be trivially replaced by `for(;x;)`.

Comment: I understand how this works, I just want to ensure that it fulfills the guidelines at the top, the differences between sorting algorithms are not my strong suite unfortunately

Comment: So you want us to tell you if you code calls `malloc()`?

Comment: No, I know it doesn't allocate any memory, I'm wondering if this is indeed a modified form of a selection sort as intended. I know I can use a for loop in that fashion as well, but I need to change this to use for loops that do something like, for( ; x; x++), but of course doing some function in the last location, I'm not sure what would need to be changed in order for this to work that way, or even if that could be done for linked list sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithm for selection sort is:

```
 int min;// min element is declared
 for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
 {
   min=i;
   for (int j = i + 1; j < size+1; ++j)
      {
        if (ar[j] < ar[min])
           {
            min = j;
            }
       }
       swap (ar[i],ar[min]);
 }
```

I have done for array
But for Link List also the concept applied will be same just there would be any variable which will be used for traversal and ar[i]  would be replaced by a function which would return the value of the node.And the list will be traverse till the end node means node.next()!=null
For the algorithm u can visit the link:
http://www.sanfoundry.com/cplusplus-program-implement-selection-sort/